# calling ssh alias with sshc strange character appear on remote host

Tags: ssh, bashrc, alias

when calling via ssh alias a remote host, strange characters appear

```
^[[6;3~fhem@UB9:~$ ;3~
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

in .bashrc

```
### add to .bash_aliases, for differentiating between multiple remote hosts
sshhelper() {
    HOST=`echo $1 | cut -d'@' -f2`

    case $HOST in
        fhem )  PROFILE="FHEM" ;;
    esac

    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x  bash -c "ssh $1"
}

#https://superuser.com/questions/347512/can-i-have-my-terminal-background-change-based-on-hostname/1368479#1368479
alias sshc=sshhelper
```

tried this line with and without ;

```
        gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x  bash -c "ssh $1"
```

and hints?

thanks

---

see result of sshc fhem command

and the code

delete as required
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x  bash -c "ssh $1"

updated as required to get off ban because of pictures?

Comment: Try to add some quote around : "sshhelper"

Comment: Hi, do you mean: changing alias to : alias sshc="sshhelper"

Comment: Yes, but after re-read your post, I think it wouldn't be solve your problem.

Comment: no it did not, did it still same behaviour

Comment: your two ";" seem to be strange.

Comment: I copied it from https://superuser.com/questions/347512/can-i-have-my-terminal-background-change-based-on-hostname/1368479#1368479 , will try and remove the double ;;

Comment: Umh .. My bad it seem it's correct for a CASE statement.

Comment: it is not running with only one ;

Comment: Ok, try this : 

Add "function" before sshhelper and add one semicolon to your HOST assignment line at the end and after gnome-terminal also at the end.

Comment: Hi
thanks for help by the way,

function sshhelper() {
    HOST=`echo $1 | cut -d'@' -f2`
    case $HOST in
        fhem )  PROFILE="FHEM" ;;
        *)           PROFILE="Default" ;;
    esac;

    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x  bash -c "ssh $1";
}

no change

Comment: Have you the same output ?

Comment: Hi 
-
yes same output---^[[6;3~osmc@WohnV1osmc95RPI3:~$ ;3~
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
osmc@WohnV1osmc95RPI3:~$

Comment: Ok wait, I think I found the error. I investigate ^^

Answer (score 0):

First error :

- You need to add the `$` symbol to retrieve the output of your commands

Second error :

- Add a semicolon at the end of all your statements.

This function work as you want I think.

```
function sshhelper() {
    HOST="$(echo $@ | cut -d'@' -f2)";

    case $HOST in
        fhem ) PROFILE="FHEM" ;;
    esac

    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x  bash -c "ssh $1";
}
```

And finally add your alias :

```
alias sshc="sshhelper"
```

And don't forget to close and reopen your terminal.

---

Tried and functional.

Comment: Hi changed it as proposed: 

 
 
but still same output error: 

{^[[6;3~fhem@UB9:~$ ;3~
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'}

Comment: Can you send a screenshots ?

Comment: looks like I am not allowed to add screenshots yet...

Comment: are the links working for you?

Comment: Put it here http://www.noelshack.com

Comment: And add me a screenshot of your bash-rc

Comment: this website is in french, how do I submit?   but check, links should work , second is code of bashrc

Comment: http://www.noelshack.com/2018-43-2-1540293221-0screenshot-from-2018-10-23-12-26-32.png

Comment: [url=http://www.noelshack.com/2018-43-2-1540293216-0screenshot-from-2018-10-23-12-30-32.png][img]http://image.noelshack.com/minis/2018/43/2/1540293216-0screenshot-from-2018-10-23-12-30-32.png[/img][/url]

Comment: After the close } don't put ; and at the alias line also remove it

Comment: Oh ! And you need to put user@host not only host when you do sshc

Comment: I defined user@host in ssh-config, maybe there is an error :    host fhem
       PermitLocalCommand yes
       user fhem
       HostName 192.168.0.9

Comment: umh .. do you have fix the issue with semicolon ?

Comment: just tested it , removed the ; but no change

Comment: code. bash rc: function sshhelper() {
    HOST="$(echo $@ | cut -d'@' -f2)";

    case $HOST in
        fhem ) PROFILE="FHEM" ;;
    esac

    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x  bash -c "ssh $1";
}

alias sshc="sshhelper"

Comment: So the new terminal doesn't open is that ?

Comment: Do you have create the "FHEM" profile in gnome-terminal ?

Comment: Hi, yes FHEM is created in gnome-terminal

Comment: sorry, yes a new terminal is still opening but having the error

Comment: I think the function is not the problem now.

Comment: yes I am lost anyway. thanks for helping, ssh terminal is opening but only the strange message, anoying but working... thanks